# Woocommerce get order key

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have orders in the format `[domain]/checkout/order-received/[order_number]/key=[wc-order-key]` - how do I get `[wc-order-key]`?

So far I've done:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);

function custom_process_order($order_id)
{
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  $myuser_id = (int)$order->user_id;
  $user_info = get_userdata($myuser_id);
  $items = $order->get_items();
  foreach ($items as $item)
  {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
    $product_description = get_post_meta($item['product_id'])->post_content
  }
  return $order_id;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you need get order_key by order_id, is it correct?
If so, you can just use WC_Order property:

```
$test_order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$test_order_key = $test_order->order_key;
```

**Edited**

As mentioned *indextwo*, since Woo 3.0 there new syntax:

```
$test_order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$test_order_key = $test_order->get_order_key();
```

Comment: Don't access directly; use `$test_order-> get_order_key()`

Answer (score 7):

#### 2018 updated answer

As WooCommerce 3 changed how property calls were made, the appropriate way to  get the same information is:

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

// Added a check to make sure it's a real order

if ($order && !is_wp_error($order)) {
    $order_key = $order->get_order_key();
}
```

Note that you can easily do the same in reverse: get an order ID from an order key:

```
$order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key($order_key);
```

Comment: is order key unique in wp multisite network?

Comment: @HamidAraghi I don't know that definitively, however that's more of an issue for how WooCommerce works in & of itself. This method will work for retrieving the order key given the ID of the order.